# How to give input to a script running using nohup?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, desktop-background, nohup

I have a script running on my server, say `test.sh`. I executed it using the following command -

`nohup test.sh`

Now I want to pass an input `quit` to this script so that it'll terminate itself gracefully (The script makes many temporary files, if you pass the `quit` command, it deletes all of them and then terminates itself)

I know the PID of the process, but how do I pass a command to that PID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a bash script you could use a signal.

For example, this script will trap the signal SIGUSR1, do the cleanup and exit. If the signal is not received, it will end after 60 seconds:

```
#!/bin/bash

function graceful_exit()
{
  echo "Graceful exit..."
  # your cleanup commands
  exit 0
}

trap graceful_exit USR1

sleep 30 & wait $!

echo "Normal exit"
```

So, you run the script:

```
$ nohup script.sh
```

Then, you send the SIGUSR1 signal with `kill` using the PID you said you had:

```
$ kill -SIGUSR1 PID
```

Comment: you could explain or print what pid to sigusr1.

Comment: You have to use the process number instead of PID.

Comment: @ChrisAga thanks for the edit. It's tempting to have real running code, but I didn't want to add new elements (such as the setting of a variable) to the code. I don't know what is considered best practice in this situation though.

Comment: just pointed out, even if OP knows how to get the pid others may not know how to get it.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I would say that bac0n just answered ;-)
I have found that if you manage to post what I would call "minimum running code" you are relatively safe.
You should show how you get the PID of script.sh in a variable and use the variable in the kill command.

Comment: This does work in case of quitting. But my question was in a general sense. For example, instead of say, `quit`, what if I want to input some other command like `command1` or so?

Comment: @jindan You can use one of the many forms of [interprocess communication (IPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication): sockets, dbus, signals (as proposed), message passing ...